# "Appears to be corrupted" error when opening old iChat logs in Messages

Tags: messages, ichat

When I try to open old iChat logs (circa 2005) with Messages on Catalina, I get the following error message:

> The chat transcript “file name” could not be opened.
>
> This file appears to be corrupted and can’t be opened.

If I try to open the same file in Visual Studio Code, I get the following:

> The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.  Do you want to open it anyway?

When I choose to open it anyway, I think I can make out pretty much all the text, but there's a whole bunch of gobbledygook in there that makes it a pain to read. Here's a sample:

> typedstream��@���NSArray��NSObject��i����NSString��+AIM����������NSMutableArray���/����InstantMessage�����
> Presentity��Person�������  vp������NSDate��d�A�X�m  ؆����NSAttributedString�����
> you there?��iI
> ����NSDictionary������NSColor�����NSColor��c�ffff�����NSBackgroundColor�������?t���?^�߃=��������NSFont�����NSFont���[28c]��Helvetica�f��������I�������������anem�������A�Xә3�φ�������yup������������������?f��?���?=���������������������A�Xӷ
> G���������just checking in�����������������A�XӷZ�?��������where are you?

[This post from 2011 on Apple's discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3308710) appears to refer to a similar problem, but doesn't offer up any solution.

Any way to open these in Messages to be able to read them normally?